# Magento 2 get Bundle product price without currency symbol in final_price phtml

Tags: magento2, price, phtml, bundle-product

How to get Bundle Product Price without Currency symbol in magento 2 final_price.phtml file.
When I use

```
$product->getName()
```

It is giving the product name but when I use

```
$product->getPrice()
```

it is not giving any result.How Can I get the product only price (**without currency symbol**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got The Solution we can use

```
echo $product->getFinalPrice()
```

instead of

```
echo $product->getPrice()
```

in final_price.phtml.Then it will give the price of the product with out currency symbol.